# Font cannot be loaded with Emscripten but with g++

Tags: c++, c, emscripten, freetype

I am trying to use FreeType the first time with OpenGL in C/C++ with this tutorial: https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H 

FT_Library ft;
FT_Face face;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
if (FT_New_Face(ft, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam/Uroob-Regular.ttf", 0, &face))
    {
        std::cout << "Font could not be loaded" << std::endl;  
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to compile this it works with g++ so far as there is no error output, but with em++ (Emscripten) the font cannot be loaded as the error output "Font could not be loaded" then indicates.

I do not need THIS kind of font "Uroob-Regular.ttf", any readable Latin font would do it for me. I am under Ubuntu.

I use the flag `-s USE_FREETYPE=1` with Emscripten.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the documentation:

> The default approach for packaging is to directly map the nested file structure at compile time — relative to the compile-time command prompt directory — to the root of the virtual file system. The @ symbol can be used in a path at build time to explicitly specify where the resource will be located in the virtual file system at runtime.

You can use the example below without copying:
`--preload-file '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam/Uroob-Regular.ttf'@Uroob-Regular.ttf`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Emscripten cannot find files below the current directory, because when I try to compile it with `--preload-file "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam/Uroob-Regular.ttf"` to help it find the font it indicates: "Embedding "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/malayalam/Uroob-Regular.ttf" which is below the current directory "xxx". This is invalid since the current directory becomes the root that the generated code will see".

I don't know if this is a valid way to do so, but then I put the font file in the same directory as the cpp file. Then I used `--preload-file "Uroob-Regular.ttf"` and changed the corresponding code line to `if (FT_New_Face(ft, "Uroob-Regular.ttf", 0, &face))` and it worked for both Emscripten and g++.